# Why does integrating $\frac{1}{r}$ over a cylinder result in $2\pi z$?

Tags: integration, cylindrical-coordinates

The time average intensity is given by $I(r)=\frac{a E_0^2}{2Z r}$ (...). If we integrate  $I(r)$ over a cylinder with radius $r$ and length $z$, we get $I=2\pi z$.

---

Obviously, they used cylindrical coordinates: $\int_0^z \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^r \frac{1}{r} dr d\phi dz$. My question is: why does  $\int_0^r \frac{1}{r} dr$ seem to equal $1$ and not $\ln{r}$ ?

Thank you

Comment: $dxdydz = \textbf{r} dr d\phi dz$ in cylindrical coordinates ?

Comment: @residuetheorem ^You're missing the Jacobian.

Comment: Uh sorry Thank you so much

Comment: Poujh and ChaoticGood if one of you post his comment as an answer, I will accept the answer. If you want of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ChaoticGood says, you forgot the Jacobian. In cylindrical coordinates, $dxdydz = r dr d\phi dz$. Maybe you can review https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system#Line_and_volume_elements to get a refresher